# Instafeed limit not working with certain hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with instafeed.js and have successfully implemented it on my website. However, I had to change the hashtag filter because the client wanted to use a different hashtag. Everything worked just fine until now. The image limit is 4, but it loads everything. I changed the hashtag back, or picked another one, but it still loads 4 images.

I've found this `fiddle` so if you change the `tagName` to `sapperdjus`you'll see the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/108/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle, limit is set to a string: limit: '4'.

The documentation at http://instafeedjs.com/ says:
limit (number)
Change limit to a numer like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: 'sapperdjus',
            clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
            limit: 4
        });
        // call feed.next() on button click
         $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
          console.log(feed);
          feed.next();
         });
        feed.run();
</script>
```